# After upgrading two of my Windows 8 machines, the keyboard is "locked"... Why? How do I unlock?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

For some reason, my keyboard is locked on two machines. I get no error message, just a beep every time I try to press a key.

I'm not completely locked out, as the on screen keyboard does work.

The only time the external keyboard works [at least on my laptop], is on the lock screen, and then only on a fresh boot.

If the lock screen comes up after I have logged in, then the lock screen displays "Locked", and doesn't accept keyboard input.

What does "Locked" mean on the lock screen?

Answer (score 2):

My keyboard was locked because somehow, the accessibility option for "Filter Keyboard" was turned on.

This option filters keystrokes.

Because my settings were synced between machines...  When it got set on one machine, it got set on the other machines.

Not to self -- don't sync settings, at least basic machine settings!

Answer (score 0):

Locked just means you need to type the password to access the Start screen, or where you left off.

My first suggestion would be to check it's not the screen saver.

My second suggestion would be to see if any apps have been added to the lock screen which could be causing it to trigger.  WinKey +i Change PC Settings --> Personalize

Could you logon as a different user and see if you get the same symptoms?

If the Lock Screen is annoying you try disabling until you figure out the root cause.

Launch the local group policy editor gpedit.msc (remember the msc when searching)
Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Control Panel, and then Personalization. Double-click the “Do not display the lock screen.”

Comment: You really didn't read my question.    the problem was they keyboard, not the locked screen.   The "locked" message threw me off a bit, though.

Comment: @user73107 You are right, I misunderstood your question; glad you solved it.